# Making a input appear when specific option is selected in a dynamic jQuery form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select

Im a jQuery noob and Im stuck in this problem.

This code makes appear a form every time you click the button, and you can remove it clicking "Remove".

The problem is: I need an input to appear (one per form) when the option "Other" is selected. And make it disappear if you select "Option 1", "Option 2" or "Option 3".

You can see the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/9dgr9e3s/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>`
```

**script jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum forms allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add form button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max forms box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div></p>Name<input name="nombre" type="text" onkeyup="update()" maxlength="16" />\
        Select <select name="username" onchange="update()">\
        <option value="1">Option1</option>\
        <option value="2">Option2</option>\
        <option value="3">Option3</option>\
        <option value="4">Other</option>\
    </select><input type="hidden">\
    <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add form
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    $(document).ready(function() {update();});
})

});
```

Any idea, suggestion? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div></p>Name<input name="nombre" type="text" onkeyup="update()" maxlength="16" />\
        Select <select name="username">\
        <option value="1">Option1</option>\
        <option value="2">Option2</option>\
        <option value="3">Option3</option>\
        <option value="4">Other</option>\
    </select><input class="optional-input" style="display:none"/>\
    <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add form
    $("select").off("change");
  $("select").on("change", function(e){
      var selEl = $(e.currentTarget);
      var inputSel = "input.optional-input";
      if (e.currentTarget.value == 4) {
        //alert("other clicked");

        selEl.parent().find(inputSel).show();
      } else {
        //alert("option clicked");
        selEl.parent().find(inputSel).hide();
      }
      });
    }
});
```

I tried this here: https://jsfiddle.net/9dgr9e3s/11/ and it works as expected.

I've made some updates to your code: added a class to the input in order to be able to select it and hidden it using display property. Also, for detecting the selection event, I've added selection listeners through jQuery using .on("change", evtHandler). .off("change") is needed so that the change listeners are reset before adding new ones.

Of course, you could (and I recommend this) also create the element separately before add and attach the eventListener on each element separately rather than using the broader $("select") jQuery addressing as provided in the example.

Comment: Awesome! This is what I want. The input that appears and disappears should be hidden by default, but Its ok :) Thanks kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a button with display none and show it with javascript when selected option is 'Other'.

Something like that:

```
<style>
    .form button {
       display: none;
    }
</style>

<!-- You form here with button-->
<form class='form'>
    <select class='my-select-changer'>
            <option>Option1</option>
            <option>Other</option>
    </select>
    <button class='button-to-hide'></button>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>  
    $(".my-select-changer").change( function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        var nextButton = $(this).next('.button-to-hide');

        if (selectedValue == "Other") {
            nextButton.show();
        } else {
            nextButton.hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Grommy! It was helpful to understand better how jQuery works :)